# Track deleted records in LDAP

Tags: openldap, spring-ldap

We are using OpenLDAP 2.3 to store contacts.

We have built a java project using Spring LDAP to do weekly export of the contacts. In the export file we flag if a contact is newly added or if an existing contact is modified. This works fine. The issue is when a contact is deleted in LDAP. When a contact is deleted, the whole record is removed in LDAP.

Is there a way in LDAP to keep a track of deleted records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Openldap has an audit module you can add in. You would have to query that to see what was deleted in the last period. Another option outside of ldap is to keep a list of contacts of exported from the previous run and compare the two at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Will look into the audit module. We have tried the option of comparing the previous export to the current but trying to eliminate as much manual tasks as possible.

Comment: We have implemented the audit module for Openldap and it is capturing the deleted records. Thanks!